# Name all instances of a movieclip dragged on to the stage (AS2)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, movieclip

I have a number of instances of a MovieClip on stage. These are dragged onto the stage and arranged manually. Now, I would like to alter the instances during run time, using as2 code.

My question is, how can I name all the instances of the same MovieClip dragged onto the stage, using as2 code?
(Please specify if the solution involves exporting the library MovieClip with an identifier name)

Answer (score 0):

On the frame that has your symbols:

```
for(var i:String in this)
{
    var obj:Object = this[i];

    obj.name = "whatever";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to name only the instances of a specific MovieClip in the library (There are instances of other MovieClips in the frame). What condition should I give to filter them alone?